# sharp architecture question, nhibernate validation

Tags: nhibernate

I have marked certain properties in my domain object for the
nhibernate validation 'framework'.

If I do this in my controller explicitly:

```
ICollection<IValidationResult> test =  bla.ValidationResults();
```

I get the validation errors which I could add to my asp.net mvc
modelstate

ideally, i would like an exception being thrown during:

```
bla = blaRepository.SaveOrUpdate(bla);
```

if i try to save or update the domain object. why is this not
happening? my domain object bla derives from Entity.

do I have to register something somehow?

Thanks.

christian

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this blog entry I wrote applies in your situation.  It's hard to tell from your description.

[Using NHibernate Validator Event Based Validation](http://www.capprime.com/software_development_weblog/PermaLink,guid,99297ab9-2919-48c5-a99a-a04893437df6.aspx)